# Please Help Me Use "EXCEPT Clause" in "Neo4j"

Tags: neo4j, cypher, social-networking, except

I have some nodes in Neo4j, with friendship relation.
Now I want to query for friends of friends of one Node(ex:Kate), except the nodes that are already friends with her.
I tried this commands, but it doesn't work:

```
MATCH ( p:person {name:"Kate"} )-[friends_with*2..3] -> (pp:person)
WHERE (pp) NOT (p)->[friends_with]-(pp)
return pp;
```

OR

```
  MATCH ( p:person {name:"Kate"} )-[friends_with*2..3] -> (pp:person)
    WHERE (pp) OUT [(p)->[friends_with]-(pp)]
    return pp;
```

I will appreciate if any one could help

Comment: *2..3 will give you friends of friends as well as friends of friends of friends. Use *2 if you only want friends of friends.

Comment: Yeah, I know and thanX for your point but that's not the matter. 
My problem is the next Condition, the "Except" part!
for example when I have:
KATE --friends_with--ALICE and KATE--friend_with--TINA and ALICE--friends_with--TINA and ALICE--friends_with--SHILA.
I want the query, that only gives me the name, SHILA

Comment: as a tip: always add details to "it doesn't work". does is return false results or does your query result in an error etc. etc.

Comment: OK, thanks for the tip @Joshua

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Almost there, just syntax:

```
MATCH (p:person {name:"Kate"})-[:friends_with*2..3]->(pp:person)
WHERE NOT ((p)-[:friends_with]->(pp))
return pp;
```

BTW, you've considered the direction as well. So if `(pp)-[:friends_with]->(p)`, it won't be excluded. If that was not the intention then just leave off the directions.

Comment: ThanX for yur answer, but it doesn't work yet :(
I got this Error:
Type mismatch: expected Relationship but was    Collection<Relationship> (line 2, column 17 (offset: 80))
"WHERE NOT ((p)-[friends_with]->(pp))"

Comment: Sorry, typed too fast. The : is missing from the rel type, I've edited my answer